# How to download image using vue js and laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have a hyperlink button on click of this, i want to fetch image from database and get it downloaded on user side with use of laravel and vue js. Below is my code for script file

```
 getImage: function() {
            axios.get('/getImage/' + this.form.cashout_id )
            .then(function (r) 
                {
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([r.data]));
                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = url;
                link.setAttribute('download', 'file.'+r.headers.ext); //or any other extension
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();

                //hide loader
                i.loader = false
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                        alert('Error');
            });
        },
```

and now this is my controller code where image is being fetched.

```
public function getimage($id)
   { 
       $cashout = CashOutDetail::findorfail($id);
       $storage_date = Carbon::parse($cashout['recorded_date']);

       return response()->download(
           storage_path('app/cashoutdetails/'. $storage_date->year .'/' . $storage_date->format('M') . '/'.  $cashout->bank_receipt),
           'filename.jpg',
           ['Content-Type' => 'image/jpg']
       );
   }
```

Issue is that my image is being fetched and displayed in console window but unable to download. Can anybody help?

Comment: Can you verify that link successfully build. `console.log(link)`

Comment: does a download link work to your file, without the JS?


<a href="/getImage/{cahshout_id}" download="proposed_file_name">Download</a>

Comment: You might be able to determine the URL of the file in your Vue/JS code if you already have the `cashout.recorded_date`. I am not sure what the best practices are but it will eliminate the HTTP request and probably be easier to render the download button/link

Comment: @xuma Yes. link is being build. but it comes as undefined and image which is being downloaded also comes as invalid file. <a href="blob:http://localhost:81-46e3-ba21-1eca8430c4e9" download="file.undefined">

Comment: @BernardWiesner yes download link is working but the file which is downloaded shows invalid file due to extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try:

```
axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/getImage/123.jpg',
    responseType: 'blob', // <-<<<<<<<<<< 
  }).then((response) => {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', '123.jpg');
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
  });
```

Comment: Thankyou !! It worked . All i needed to change 123.jpg with my cashout id parameter.